# Jquery newbie - menu issues

Tags: jquery

I'm dynamically creating a menu in a cms using smarty.  I have got it to generate jquery for my menu as well as the html.  I'm using classes to close menu items and ids to open them.  (see logic below).  It's all good apart from if someone clicks on the same menu item twice - in which case it closes the item then reopens it.  I've tried changing id on the item too but that doesn't solve the issue.

Example code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about-us').click(function() {
        $('.second-level-menu').slideUp('fast', function() {});
        $('#about-us-menu').slideDown('fast', function() {});
        $('#about-us').attr('id', 'about-us-close');
    });

    $('#about-us-close').click(function() {
        $('#about-us-menu').slideUp('fast', function() {});
        $('#about-us-close').attr('id', 'about-us');
    });
});
```

You can see the code and issue by looking at 
http://pfp.pearsonwebsnorthampton.co.uk - click about us, then click it again.

Comment: `$('#about-us').click(function() {` where is your `#about-us` exactly?

Comment: You need event delegation if you're gonna change the ID of the element, it should be `$('#top_navigation').on('click', '#about-us', function() {` and `$('#top_navigation').on('click', '#about-us-close', function() {`

Comment: Great! Thanks - that's worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you got your binding done here:
`$('#about-us').click(function() {`

But when the document is ready `#about-us-ready` does not exist so the second set of binding:
`$('#about-us-close').click(function() {`
can't happen correctly.

You can use event delegation to fix this problem or set your event binding to one function and simply have the function check to see what state your DOM object is currently in (open or closed)

Comment: Thanks! That's helped